# Lyrics meaning and grammar - "Je t'aime à l'italienne"

Tags: grammaire, paroles-de-chanson

I'm trying to understand the lyrics of the song *Je t'aime à l'italienne* by Frédéric François. If anyone could help me translate the underlined parts and explain the grammar behind these, that would be great!

> Oh oh oh oh **je t'aime à l'italienne** x2
>
> J'ai au fond du cœur une drôle de chanson sicilienne.
>
> Que tu sais par cœur car ma vie ressemble à la tienne
> Je t'aime plus fort que les volcans de l'Italie.
> Quand **résonne** encore les bruits de verres de Chianti.

(not sure which subject "résonne" corresponds to, but something seems wrong to me with the grammar)

Answer (score 2):

> *je t'aime à l'italienne*

= I love you the Italian way

> *Quand résonne encore les bruits…*

There is a retranscription or grammar mistake here, that should be

> *Quand **résonnent** encore les bruits…*

Comment: Thanks @jilliagre for your answer. The original lyrics actually reads "Quand résonne". Would there be a reason for the intentional grammatical mistake?

Comment: No particular reason, the mistake is likely unintentional, and insignificant when compared to what rap lyrics might produce ;-)